# custom rosdep rules

Tags: rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am migrating to fuerte and I am having problem with rosdep 2. We have a bunch of packages and we used to have a bunch of rosdep rules to support our packages. I am wondering what I am supposed to do with rosdep2?

I tried creating /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/30-myrosdep.list with a line such as: "yaml file://path/to/my/rosdep.yaml", but it was rejected.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50660/custom-rosdep-rules/) by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1001 on 2012-12-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Brice,

the URI needs a hostname, so it should look like this:

```
file://localhost/home/martin/code/rosdistro/rosdep/base.yaml
```

The instructions from the [official documentation](http://ros.org/doc/api/rosdep2/html/contributing_rules.html) tell you to first push to your forked github repo and then directly use your github links, but I prefer testing my rules locally (using a set of rules like the one above) before pushing to github.

You should still create a github account, fork the repository etc. (as explained in the page I linked to) and edit the forked files. Your sources.list.d entry should point to those files. That way, when you're satisfied, you can submit a pull request so everybody can use your rosdep rules.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2012-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-12-18**:
It might also be a good idea to check if there already is a rule in rosdep. I found many packages actually already in there.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-12-18**:
An additional slash should also work: `file:///home/martin/code/rosdistro/rosdep/base.yaml`.

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2012-12-18**:
@joq: It should, but it doesn't. Rosdep insists on a hostname even for `file://` schemes; this is a bug in rosdep.